# Combining DataTables obtained from DataSet.ReadXML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview, ado.net

I have a DataGridView that I would like to populate with data read from an XML file which I read from a network folder. These XML files have different schemas, the most complex of which resembles the following structure.

> Orders (Attribute 1)
>
> > Order (Attribute 2) (Attribute 3)
> >
> > > Line
> > >
> > > > Line Number
> > > >         Part Number
> > > >         Serial Number

This data is read into memory through a combination of FileInfo.OpenText, XmlReader.Create, and DataSet.ReadXML. When DataSet.ReadXML executes, I am returned a DataSet object (named "xmlContents") with three DataTables: Orders, Order and Line. I wish to bind this data to a single DataGridView in a Windows Form application I am creating.

When I tried merging the data tables together, using the below methodology, I get a Null Reference Exception.

```
foreach (DataTable dt in xmlContents.Tables)
            {
                if (onFirstTable)
                {
                    mergedTable = dt.Clone();
                    onFirstTable = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    mergedTable.Merge(dt);
                }
            }
```

I have checked, and there ARE DataRelations between the three different tables.   However, the columns are system-generated.   Is there a way, perhaps using LINQ, that I can return a DataSet that would combine the data from these three tables into a single DataTable?   I would like to do this in a generic manner, without having to write a LINQ such as

`from x join y join z 
select x.Attribute1, y.Attribute2, y.Attribute3, z.LineNumber, z.PartNumber, z.SerialNumber`

as different files have the different schemas, and I do not know the names of the system-generated primary keys at build-time.

---

Edit: I have implemented a LINQ query, after determining what the ystem-generated PKs were for my tables.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = 
                (from rpos in xmlContents.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                join rpo in xmlContents.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                    on rpos.Field<object>("RPOs_Id") equals rpo.Field<object>("RPOs_Id")
                join line in xmlContents.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
                    on rpo.Field<object>("RPO_Id") equals line.Field<object>("RPO_Id")
                select new { rpos, rpo, line }).Cast<DataRow>();
```

However, when running the application I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow]' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Answer (score 0):

This is two tables, but you should be able to expand it to three (take baby steps!):

```
//Create source tables
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Employees");
dt1.Columns.Add("EmployeeID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt1.Columns.Add("FirstName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt1.Columns.Add("LastName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt1.Columns.Add("BirthDate", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
dt1.Columns.Add("JobTitle", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt1.Columns.Add("DepartmentID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Tommy", "Hill", new DateTime(1970, 12, 31), "Manager", 42 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Brooke", "Sheals", new DateTime(1977, 12, 31), "Manager", 23 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Bill", "Blast", new DateTime(1982, 5, 6), "Sales Clerk", 42 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Kevin", "Kline", new DateTime(1978, 5, 13), "Sales Clerk", 42 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Martha", "Seward", new DateTime(1976, 7, 4), "Sales Clerk", 23 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Dora", "Smith", new DateTime(1985, 10, 22), "Trainee", 42 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Elvis", "Pressman", new DateTime(1972, 11, 5), "Manager", 15 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Johnny", "Cache", new DateTime(1984, 1, 23), "Sales Clerk", 15 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Jean", "Hill", new DateTime(1979, 4, 14), "Sales Clerk", 42 });
dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Anna", "Smith", new DateTime(1985, 6, 26), "Trainee", 15 });

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Departments");
dt2.Columns.Add("DepartmentID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt2.Columns.Add("DepartmentName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 15, "Men's Clothing" });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 23, "Women's Clothing" });
dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 42, "Children's Clothing" });

var JoinedTables = from t1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    join t2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on t1["DepartmentID"] equals t2["DepartmentID"]
                    select new {
                        LastName = t1.Field<String>("LastName"),
                        DepartmentName = t2.Field<String>("DepartmentName")
                    };

GridView1.DataSource = JoinedTables;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how much different this is than in my example?     I'm still getting the error about casting objects.

Comment: The difference seems to be mine works and yours doesn't.